# Click anywhere in the page to close div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an overlay div that fades in when I click on a DOM element. I would like to be able to close it when I click anywhere on the page ( except the div itself) but it does not work..
    Here is my code:

```
    //Script for showing the DIV called overlay.
       <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#loginfooter').click(function(){
                $('#overlay').fadeIn(200,function(){
                    $('#box').animate({'top':'20px'},'slow');


                });
                return false;
            });
            $('#boxclose').click(function(){
                $('#box').animate({'top':'-800px'},500,function(){
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                });
            });


        });
    </script>

//Script for hiding the div after clicking anywhere..
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#overlay').on('click',function(ev){
                var myID = ev.target.id;
                if(myID!=='overlay'){
                    $('#box').animate({'top':'-800px'},500,function(){
                        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                    });
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
```

Comment: This is what you need: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/

Comment: Could you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @elclanrs, there must be a way to do this without plugin!

Comment: Well, if you're doing it often it will help. The plugin is _very_ small, less than 1K https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-outside-events/v1.1/jquery.ba-outside-events.min.js

Comment: @Niklas jsfiddle.net/YLBwr

Comment: Hm, seems to be working in FireFox. Maybe I don't fully understand what you need?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YLBwr/2/ Sorry I didnt update it @Niklas

Comment: @Suvimo but how could you click anywhere else except overlay div when your overlay div take all the window space???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this:

```
$('#overlay').on('click', function (ev) {
```

with this

```
$(document).on('click', function (ev) {
```

and try again....

Actually, when you are clicking on the `overlay` element, the `myID` variable value is always `== 'overlay'`. Hence, it never goes inside the if statement.

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). I will have to look into it...

Comment: jsfiddle.net/YLBwr Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/YLBwr/)

```
$(document).on('click',function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).closest('#overlay').length)
        $('#overlay').hide();
});
```

Other possibility without using any delegate event:

[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lm6Z/)

```
$('#overlay').on('blur', function (e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Even you'll see most people using the first method, using the second one will avoid to have to use any delegate event which is better IMO. You just have to set focus on overlay when open it or when added to DOM, depending your specific case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YLBwr/
Please see this fiddle that explains the situation more.

Comment: Actually, this solution, ignore the fact that there is a box in the overlay.

Comment: @Suvimo No, have you tested my jsfiddle? The one you have reposted in comment

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. No effect at all unfortunately. I would appreciate if you could try it yourself there!

Comment: Which browser are you using? I have tested it and as i understand your question, it works as expected. Could you provide a jsfiddle with your relevant HTML code?  {when i click outside overlay DIV, overlay is hidden. Clicking inside has no effect. Isn't it what you are looking for???}

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLBwr/4/)?

I changed this:

```
if(myID!=='overlay'){
```

to this

```
if(myID=='overlay'){
```

so that you target the overlay instead of the box.